# ProgressBar not updating while showing download progress using PyTube in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I'm working on a Kivy application that is using PyTube for downloading videos. I have a ProgressBar widget that should display the download progress, but it is not updating during the download process. Here's the relevant code snippet:

This is my `download` function and inside it, I am using `on_progress` function to see the download progress and as the code is executing well and showing progress on `console` only but not updating the same on `progressBar` widget. Even after using the `Clock.schedule_once`. Still not happening. I'm not sure where am I doing wrong. Struck in this deadlock. Please help me out.

```
def download(self, instance):
    try:
        print("Inside download button")

    def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):

        global download_start_time
        seconds_since_download_start = (datetime.now() - download_start_time).total_seconds()
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
        speed = round(((bytes_downloaded / 1024) / 1024) / seconds_since_download_start, 2)
        seconds_left = round(((bytes_remaining / 1024) / 1024) / float(speed), 2)

        print("percentage_of_completion:", round(percentage_of_completion, 2), "%")
        self.progress = round(percentage_of_completion, 2)
        print(f"Its progress Value : {self.progress}")

    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.update_Progress_Bar(self.progress))
    self.yt.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
    self.progressBar.ids.progress_bar.value = 100
    self.ys = self.yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').filter(resolution=self.resolutionButton.text).first()

    print("Downloading...")

    self.ys.download("D:/Songs")
    print("Download Complete")
    self.progress_bar.value = 100

except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
    # Handle the exception
    print("IncompleteRead exception occurred: ", str(e))
    # Retry the request or perform other error handling logic
```

Update Progress Bar Function

```
def update_Progress_Bar(self,value):
        print("Inside update progress bar function")
        self.progressBar.ids.progress_bar.value = value
```